# Struts 2 token is not working with display tag pagination

Tags: jsp, struts2, pagination, csrf, displaytag

I have a Struts 2 application, I have created some reports with **display tag  pagination**, it works fine but when I apply CSRF token to that page, **only first page displays properly** and when I try to navigate other paginated pages application shows `invalid.token` error.

Can anyone please suggest how to apply CSRF token with display tag ?

Comment: This is a nice question

Comment: Why do you need that token there, change displaytag with something newer. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Any good reason to use tokens in pagination?

Comment: Actually the application is under security audit, and the audit team has suggested to implement CSRF token to prevent CSRF attacks that's why I have to implement token.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) - *...apply the protection only to HTTP methods that are intended to be state-changing.*

Comment: One thing you can do is create your own token, send it with a request and apply it on hidden field and do the needful checks in your action method(or in validate method). I agree here with @RomanC, use http://www.jtable.org/ or Jqgrid.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for valuable inputs, I managed to convince audit team    on "apply the protection only to HTTP methods that are intended to be state-changing".